# XML unmarshalling in Golang

Tags: go

I want to unmarshall the below xml payload to struct

```
<linearPackagePublish>
                <linearPackage>
                    <name>ABC</name>
                    <packagedServiceReference>
                        <availabilityWindowEnd>2329-12-31 23:59:59</availabilityWindowEnd>
                        <availabilityWindowStart>2007-11-14 11:40:00</availabilityWindowStart>
                        <packagedServiceId>1111111111</packagedServiceId>
                    </packagedServiceReference>
                    <partnerPackageId>XXXXXXX</partnerPackageId>
                </linearPackage>
                <partnerId>XXXXXX</partnerId>
                <wantLinearPublishResult>true</wantLinearPublishResult>
            </linearPackagePublish>
```

I want to add transactionId just before  tag like this:

```
<linearPackagePublish>
                <linearPackage>
                    <name>ABC</name>
                    <packagedServiceReference>
                        <availabilityWindowEnd>2329-12-31 23:59:59</availabilityWindowEnd>
                        <availabilityWindowStart>2007-11-14 11:40:00</availabilityWindowStart>
                        <packagedServiceId>1111111111</packagedServiceId>
                    </packagedServiceReference>
                    <partnerPackageId>XXXXXXX</partnerPackageId>
                </linearPackage>
                <partnerId>XXXXXX</partnerId>
        <transactionId>111111111111</transactionId>
                <wantLinearPublishResult>true</wantLinearPublishResult>
            </linearPackagePublish>
```

For this purpose I was trying to unmarshall the above xml to below struct:

```
type linearPackagePublish struct {
    LinearPackage           string `xml:"linearPackage"`
    MsoPartnerID            string `xml:"partnerId"`
    TransactionID           string `xml:"transactionId,omitempty"`
    WantLinearPublishResult bool   `xml:"wantLinearPublishResult,omitempty"`
}
```

But the thing is I don’t want to unmarshall the linearPackage element that is why I put LinearPackage as string in struct

I can also do it via regex but it will be more error prone if something change in the xml.

Is there any way that we can make some nested xml element as a string??

Comment: It would help to make a runnable example, perhaps with a link to the playground.

Comment: you should not put LinearPackage as string intead use LinearPackage           xml.CharData `xml:"linearPackage"` 
it would be better if you provide some code examples of what you want with comments and end results

Answer (score 1):

Edited to provide more detail. Including a working demo on [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nIEtDGppnvk)

Rather than trying to use a string you can define a custom type, with its own marshal and unmarshal functions defined. That way you can have direct control over that element.

You can see the custom datatype holds an array of xml.Tokens. This array is populated during unmarshalling and then written to the encoder during marshalling.

```
type skipUnmarshal struct {
    data []xml.Token
}

func (s skipUnmarshal) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    for i := 0; i < len(s.data); i++ {
        e.EncodeToken(s.data[i])
    }
    return nil
}
func (s *skipUnmarshal) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            break // or alternatively return the error
        }
        s.data = append(s.data, t)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm new to golang, can u pls elaborate.

Comment: @vikashsingh sure thing - see edits to post